# Is there a way to reset my Talents in Hogwarts Legacy?

Tags: hogwarts-legacy

I want to know if there is a way to reset my Talents in Hogwarts Legacy.

I've used up all my Talent Points, but I'm not happy with the Talents I've chosen to spend it on. So I'd like to choose other Talents, but it doesn't seem like I'm able to reset my Talents.

I spent some Talent Points on things from the "Room of Requirement" category, but I don't want it there anymore as can be seen by the below screenshot:

[image: Talent Points for Room of Requirement]

Is it possible somehow to reset my Talent Points or move it from one to another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**. Not without modding the game.

It's not currently possible to reset your Talent Points or move them to a different perk. Once they are set, then they're set in stone.

You do however get more than enough points throughout the game to eventually max everything out.

---

There is actually a mod already released that allows you to reset your Talent Points. The mod is called "Talent Reset Potion" and you can find it on [nexusmods](https://www.nexusmods.com/hogwartslegacy/mods/220).

The mod ﻿adds a talent reset potion, the recipe can be bought from J Pippin's potion store in Hogsmeade:

[image: Talent Reset Potion]
[image: Talent Reset Potion]
[image: Talent Reset Potion]